# In doxygen, how to remove a specific file from the File menu

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I use a markdown page to generate my doxygen home page with the following approach:

```
INPUT                  = <path to my .md file> \
                         <path to my header files>
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = <path to my .md file>
SHOW_FILES             = YES
```

However in the Files tab, this shows my header files but also the path to my .md file (without showing the .md file itself).  I would like the File tab to only show my header files but not the path to my .md file.

So far, the only workaround I found was to locate my .md file in the same directory in which my header files are located.

Is there a way for my .md file to be located in a different place than my header files without showing that path in the doxygen Files tab?

Comment: I don't think this is possible as you explicitly specify the header files, or do they have a special meaning, so they fit in the `INCLUDE..` or `EXAMPLE..` category?

Comment: Which version of doxygen do you use? In the versions I used I don't see this behavior. You write `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = <path to my .md file>` is this path also including the name of the md file (as it should)?

Comment: I use 1.8.15.  Yes, <path to my .md file> includes the name of the md file itself. What behavior do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer but too long for a comment (and there is an image):

**Doxyfile**:

```
INPUT                  = bb.md \
                         aa.h
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = bb.md
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
```

**aa.h**:

```
/// \file
```

**bb.md**:

```
The markdown file
```

The resulting image:

[image]

Comment: I started from your example and wanted to illustrate that if bb.md was a in a different folder than aa.h, then the bb.m folder would show and... it didn't. I re-added my other options to the config file until I realized it was my EXTRACT_ALL            = YES that was causing that unwanted folder to appear. Thank you for thinking of starting from a trivial example!